# what is class of tab bar item

Tags: iphone

When I connect element from xib to header file. It gives me

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITabBarItem *contract;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITabBarItem *history;
```

However, when I try to print out the subiew of my tabBar ( type of UITabBar), I am getting 2 UITabBarButton.

My question is what is class of tab bar item.Is it UITabBarItem or UITabBarButton

Comment: Why are you printing its subviews anyway?

Comment: for some purposes.....I set tag for them but I can not get their tags back..

Comment: You seem to be dipping yourself into swamp goop... don't do it. If you need to assign tags to views, don't just take a built-in view and loop through its subviews. Use views that you know and have direct access to.

Comment: ok so ignore to set tag. my question is why i got subviews are uitabbarbutton......

Answer (score 2):

Firstly: what you're doing is not recommended. You're not meant to rely on private subviews of Apple views, as they can change at any time.

To actually answer the question as posed, it's because `UITabBarItem` is not actually a view, so won't ever end up in your view hierarchy. What presumably happens somewhere in the `UITabBar` code is, the `UITabBarItem`s are iterated through, and for each one the system makes a new view of class `UITabBarButton`, which is a private subclass of `UIControl`.

You're never meant to access a `UITabBarButton` directly. As BoltClock was pointing out in the comments, you should rethink your design so that you don't need to do this.